# How to mark Swift declaration as available in iOS and unavailable in macOS

Tags: swift

I have a class that only works on iOS 10.0 and up. It's in a Swift package, so Xcode 11 is trying to compile it for macOS too, and complaining. How do I say that it's available on iOS 10.0 only.

These don't work:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class Thing { ... }

@available(macOS, unavailable)
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class Thing { ... }
```

Some docs: 
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html

Comment: "It's in a Swift package, so Xcode 11 is trying to compile it for macOS too" I think there is a misconception here. Xcode does not try to compile a Swift package "for macOS too". All it does is compile your app target along with its dependencies. If your app is an iOS app, compiling for iOS is all that happens. Something else must be going on.

Comment: I've opened the package by itself, and there is an option to "Build" under the "Product" menu. My goal is to build the package (a library) and run it's unit tests. I did pick "My Mac" in the scheme selector in the toolbar, because I want to run the unit tests on the Mac without booting a simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it inside this

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
    // iOS Only code
#endif
```

This way it will remove from compiled project if it's not going to iOS device.

You can check with OS type like `#if os(iOS)` too, but be specific to why you should care about the OS? isn't it because of something especially for iOS like `UIKit` ? If not, be more general and limit the `OS` as @Shreeram mentioned.

Comment: Actually I would suggest doing what the compiler tells you to do: surround UIKit imports and mentions of UIKit types with `#if !os(macOS)` and `#endif`.

Answer (score 7):

From docs

> iOS iOSApplicationExtension macOS macOSApplicationExtension watchOS
>   watchOSApplicationExtension tvOS tvOSApplicationExtension swift You
>   can also use an asterisk (*) to indicate the availability of the
>   declaration on all of the platform names listed above.

So * in @available(iOS 10.0, *) saying that declaration is available in all the  other platforms. But we are also specifying that it is not available in macOS. So in the end compiler gets confused and availability wins the war. Instead of using @available you can use compiler flags,

```
#if os(iOS)
#endif
```

to specify the compiler to compile code only on iOS.