# @available(watchOS, unavailable) is not blocking compiling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, watchos

I am developing a package with UI components that support ios and WatchOS. The package has textfields and i don't want them to used in watchOS. i marked them as unavailable using available macro. Attached code snippet for the component. When i try to build this package for watchOS, it fails saying i used api that is unsupported for watchOS. My assumption is since this component shouldn't be in watchOS, it shouldn't be involved in compiling process

```
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
public struct QuantityTextField: View {
    private var placeholder: String
    @Binding private var text: String
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    public init(placeholder: String,
                text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .focused($isFocused)
    }
}
```

[image: Compiler error]

Comment: Make sure this file isn’t a part of the watch “Target Membership”

Comment: [This should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58015325/5133585)